# Return same result even no signal quotation mark in string using RowFilter

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I understand I should put the single quotation mark between the string for RowFilter like that

```
dim TOS as string="04"
rowFilter.RowFilter = "(TOScode= " & "'" & TOS & "')"
```

I just wonder why the following code still work without single quotation mark.

```
        rowFilter.RowFilter = "(TOScode = " & TOS & ") "
```

The TOScode field is varchar(2) type in SQL. English is not my native language; please excuse typing errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
rowFilter.RowFilter = String.Format("(TOScode = '{0}')", TOS)
```

OR simply as

```
rowFilter.RowFilter = String.Format("TOScode = '{0}'", TOS)
```

Comment: Thanks. Both of my code are return same value without error. I am curious why it work without single quation mark.